# Vue leaflet marker does not stand still when zooming in on the map

Tags: vue.js

I have a rather strange problem with using Vue leafet.

I put some pins on the map but they are not fixed where they are when zooming.
Do you think it's a problem with the map or my code?
In the documentation when I tested their map, the markers were fixed
This is my code

```
 <l-map style="height: 100vh;" :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-marker
          v-for="marker, index in markers"
          :lat-lng="marker.address"
          :key="index"
          :icon="icons[marker.status]"
      >
</l-map>
```

Icons

```
icons: {
          'Unused': new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-grey.png',
            shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            shadowSize: [41, 41]
        }),
```